# Props in initial arguments of styled component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, emotion

I've made this utility component that allows some simple props:

```js
export const CenterFlexRow = styled.div<{
  bordered?: boolean
  margined?: boolean
  padded?: boolean
}>({
  display: 'flex',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  position: 'relative',
}, props =>
  Object.assign({},
    props.bordered && { border: 'solid thin black' },
    props.margined && { margin: 10 },
    props.padded && { padding: 10 },
  ))
```

I can use it like this:

```js
const CarouselWrapper = styled(CenterFlexRow)({})

return <CarouselWrapper bordered padded>
  ...
</CarouselWrapper>
```

But is there a way I can put the props in the *definition* of `CarouselWrapper` so that my use of that component can be simpler?

This works but I wish it could be way shorter:

```js
const CarouselWrapper = ({ children }: any) =>
  <CenterFlexRow bordered padded children={children}/>
```